# Recode values in R

Tags: r, recode

I want to recode the values in a column
if x is >1 but < 2, it will be recoded as 1

Here's my code:

```
neu$b <- lapply(neu$swl.y, function(x) ifelse(x>1 & x<=2, 1, x))
```

Is there sth wrong?

```
 swl.y

  2.2
  1.2
  3.4
  5.6
```

I need to recode all the values actually:

```
  neu$c <- with(neu, ifelse(swl.y>1 & swl.y <=2, 1, swl.y))
  neu$c <- with(neu, ifelse(swl.y>2 & swl.y <=3, 2, swl.y))
  neu$c <- with(neu, ifelse(swl.y>3 & swl.y <=4, 3, swl.y))
  neu$c <- with(neu, ifelse(swl.y>4 & swl.y <=5, 4, swl.y))
  neu$c <- with(neu, ifelse(swl.y>5 & swl.y <=6, 5, swl.y))
  neu$c <- with(neu, ifelse(swl.y>6 & swl.y <=7, 6, swl.y))
```

I think I know where the problem is. When R runs the second line of code, the recoded values were back to the previous values.

Comment: In the updated dataset, the condition is not matching because none of the elements satisfy the condition  `swl.y>1 & swl.y<=2` for the example showed

Comment: just edited it, I'm sure there's value satisfy the condition in my sample.

Comment: Yes, it does now `with(neu1, ifelse(swl.y>1 & swl.y <=2, 1, swl.y))
#[1] 2.2 1.0 3.4 5.6`  Check that 1.2 is replace by 1.  Just assign it to `neu1$b <- ` to create a new column

Comment: Can you check whether your column `sw1.y` is numeric or not.  i.e. `str(neu)`.  If the column is not numeric.  For example, if it is `factor` , then convert it to numeric. ie.d `neu1$sw1.y <- as.numeric(as.character(neu1$sw1.y))`

Comment: it's so weird, I checked, it's numeric, but the methods just don't work on my data, still looking for the problem

Comment: As I mentioned, your latest update is working for me.  It is better to show the example using `dput` i.e. `dput(head(neu))`

Comment: If you have multiple values, then it is better to use `?cut` instead of doing this individually

Comment: i.e. `with(neu, cut(sw1.y, breaks=c(-Inf,1,2,3,4,5,6,Inf), labels=F)-1)#[1] 2 1 3 5`

Comment: Perfect, this is what I want, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need to loop for a single column.  By using `lapply(neu$swl.y`, we are getting each element of the column as the `list` element, which we may not need.  The function `ifelse` is vectorized and can be used directly on the column 'swl.y' with the logical condition mentioned in the OP's post.

```
 neu$b <- with(neu, ifelse(swl.y>1 & swl.y <=2, 1, swl.y))
```

Or otherwise, we create 'b' column as 'swl.y' and change the values of 'b' based on the logical condition.

```
 neu$b <- neu$swl.y
 neu$b[with(neu, swl.y>1 & swl.y <=2)] <- 1
```

---

To better understand the problem with the OP's code, we can check the output from the `lapply`

```
 lapply(neu$swl.y, function(x) x) #similar to `as.list(neu$swl.y)`
 #[[1]]
 #[1] 3

 #[[2]]
 #[1] 0

 #[[3]]
 #[1] 0

 #[[4]]
 #[1] 2

 #[[5]]
 #[1] 1
```

The output is a `list` with each element of the column as `list` elements.  Using `ifelse` on a list may not be optimum as it is vectorized (already mentioned above).  But, suppose if we do with `ifelse`

```
lapply(neu$swl.y, function(x) ifelse(x>1 & x<=2, 1, x))
#[[1]]
#[1] 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 0

#[[3]]
#[1] 0

#[[4]]
#[1] 1

#[[5]]
#[1] 1
```

A `data.frame` can be considered as a `list` with list elements that are having the same length.  So, based on the above output, this should be a data.frame with 5 columns and 1 row.  By assinging to a single column 'b', we are instead creating a `list` column with 5 list elements.

```
 neu$b <- lapply(neu$swl.y, function(x) ifelse(x>1 & x<=2, 1, x))
 str(neu)
 #'data.frame': 5 obs. of  2 variables:
 #$ swl.y: int  3 0 0 2 1
 #$ b    :List of 5
 # ..$ : int 3
 # ..$ : int 0
 # ..$ : int 0
 # ..$ : num 1
 # ..$ : int 1
```

But, this is not we wanted.  What is the remedy? One way is using `sapply/vapply` instead of `lapply` which returns a `vector` output as the lengths are the same or we `unlist` the `lapply` output to create a `vector`

```
 neu$b <- sapply(neu$swl.y, function(x) ifelse(x>1 & x<=2, 1, x))
 str(neu) 
 #'data.frame': 5 obs. of  2 variables:
 # $ swl.y: int  3 0 0 2 1
 # $ b    : num  3 0 0 1 1
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's edited post, if we need multiple recodes, use either `cut` or `findInterval`.  In the `cut`, we can specify the `breaks` and there are other arguments `labels` to return the default label or not.

```
 with(neu1, cut(swl.y, breaks=c(-Inf,1,2,3,4,5,6,Inf), labels=F)-1)
 #[1] 2 1 3 5
```

#### data

```
set.seed(48)
neu <- data.frame(swl.y=sample(0:5, 5, replace=TRUE))

#newdata 
neu1 <- structure(list(swl.y = c(2.2, 1.2, 3.4, 5.6)), 
.Names = "swl.y", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I don't know what's the problem of my data, I tried all the methods you provided but b is still exactly the same with swl.y. I've updated my dataset

Comment: @Lucia There was a typo in my code.  At some places, I typed `new` instead of `neu`